# What is source of local videos for unity video lens?

Tags: unity, 13.04, lenses

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04. I tried to use unity music, photos and video lenses. Music and photo lenses doesn't show any result. I found that it is because it depends upon rhythmbox and shotwell databases respectively as source, which both I don't use. But upon opening video lens it shows 6 movies I have locally, but upon typing it doesn't show any result not even video it is showing upon just opening that lens.So, what is its source for local video and how does it shows those 6 movies?

Those movies are not stored in "/home/usrname/Videos" directroy and there are many more vidoes stored in that same directory.